# Save visible portion of range as a new workbook and export as PDF with the same name

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a workbook with three tabs.
First tab is for data entry.
Second tab has formulas based on information entered on the first tab.
The third tab has all reference part numbers and source URLs for images used in the second tab.

When the data is entered in the first tab, I want to save the range with data to a new workbook.  Since this new workbook will be referencing URLs and stuff from the third tab on the source workbook, I assume I'll have to paste as an image in the new workbook to preserve the information.

When I create the new workbook, I'd also like to create a PDF with the same name as the xlsx that was just created.

I am able to copy and paste to the workbook now that I removed the _.
Now, I am losing my images and everything when it copies.

How do I paste the visible* range as an image?
*Empty columns are dynamically hidden

```vb
'Option Explicit

Sub SavetoExcel()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim strfile As String

    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("BOM")

    '~~> Destination/Output Workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'setting filename with a date stamp.
         strfile = "." & "BOM" & "." & "today()" & ".xlsx"
         strfile = "C:filepath" & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Application.Cells(1, 7) & strfile
         
        '~~>. Save the file
        .SaveAs Filename:=strfile

        '~~> Copy the range
        wsI.Range("A1:R6").Copy

        '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error you're getting?  Those ~~> aren't commented so maybe start there.  And in the SaveAs you have a _ but the rest is one the same line.

Comment: I took the comment marks out earlier when trying to get the code to display correctly here, and forgot to add them back.  What is that you are saying about the SaveAs?

Comment: `wsI.Range("A1:R6").CopyPicture`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for saving to pdf

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F13").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=0, _
  Filename:="C:\Users\User\doc\" & ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value, _
  Quality:=0, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  openafterpublish:=True
```